# Error while using Accordian in React-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

Every time when I copy-paste the code of `accordion component` from the `react-bootstrap official docs`. I am getting the following error. Attached below is both code and error screenshots.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Nav, NavDropdown,Alert, Row, Col, Accordion} from 'react-bootstrap';


return (
    <>
    <div >          
        <div style={{border:'1px solid black'}} className="my-4">
            <div className="my-3 mx-3" style={{fontSize:'160%', fontFamily:'Special Elite'}}>Chess Moves Notation</div>
            <Row style={{padding:'5%',textAlign:'center'}}>
                <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" flush>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                        <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  
                        est laborum.
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
                        <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #2</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                        est laborum.
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                </Accordion>
            </Row>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    </>
)
  }

     export default PieceNotation;
```

**Error**

[image]

How can we fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using `Accordion` which the related method is used in `bootstrap-5`, but the `bootstrap` version which you've installed is `bootstrap-4`. So you need to use `bootstrap-4` related method. You should use the `Accordion` component same as bellow:

```
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" flush>
          <Card>
            <Card.Header>
              <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                Accordion Item #1
              </Accordion.Toggle>
            </Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
              <Card.Body>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                do eiusmod est laborum.
              </Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        </Accordion>
```

Please refer to this link for `Accordion` in `bootstrap-4` : [Accordion](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/accordion/)

[image: Edit wizardly-ishizaka-hn2bh]